# XSLT 1.0 How to match a string to another, list it, and under a different heading, list the unmatched string (specific situation)

Tags: xslt, parameters, xslt-1.0, string-matching

I have been training myself in XSLT for about 1.5 months.  I have made a simplified shorter version of what I am having trouble figuring out, and would highly appreciate any help at all as I am stuck on the issue.  Thanks!

**Basic Situation:**

There's a string in a root attribute with an ancestor of element definition
xpath:

```
/v3:QualityMeasureDocument/v3:component/v3:dataCriteriaSection/v3:definition/v3:valueSet/v3:id/@root
```

...that when matched with the id from a valueSet attribute with an ancestor of element entry, xpath:

```
/v3:QualityMeasureDocument/v3:component/v3:dataCriteriaSection/v3:entry/v3:observationCriteria/v3:value/@valueSet
```

or

```
/v3:QualityMeasureDocument/v3:component/v3:dataCriteriaSection/v3:entry/v3:observationCriteria/v3:code/@valueSet
```

the output (needs to and currently does) display the string, along with its required attribute(s).

However, when there is no match for the string in these locations, the string must also be listed, with a 'Not Specified' header.

**THE ERROR:**
The 'Not Specified' header and its string are being listed even when all of the existing strings match.  In this scenario, there should only be matched strings listed.

**The Problem Translator (XSL file) :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
  xmlns:v3="urn:hl7-org:v3"
  xmlns:rvs="urn:ihe:iti:svs:2008">  
  <xsl:output method="html" standalone="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>    

  <xsl:template 
    match="/v3:QualityMeasureDocument">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test 'I'</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//v3:dataCriteriaSection" />
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template
    match="v3:dataCriteriaSection">    
    <xsl:for-each select="//v3:entry">      
      <xsl:if test="*/v3:value/@valueSet">                    
        <xsl:call-template name="definitionValueSet">
          <xsl:with-param name="cur_valueSetID" select="*/v3:value/@valueSet"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:if>      
      <xsl:if test="*/v3:code/@valueSet">               
        <xsl:call-template name="definitionValueSet">
          <xsl:with-param name="cur_valueSetID" select="*/v3:code/@valueSet"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:if>      
      <xsl:if test="*/v3:participant/v3:roleParticipant/v3:code/@valueSet">                     
        <xsl:call-template name="definitionValueSet">
          <xsl:with-param name="cur_valueSetID" select="*/v3:participant/v3:roleParticipant/v3:code/@valueSet"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:if>                  
    </xsl:for-each>                
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template
    name="definitionValueSet">  
    <xsl:param name="cur_valueSetID"/>                     
    <xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet">                                
      <xsl:choose>    
        <xsl:when test="$cur_valueSetID != v3:id/@root or
        not( v3:text/v3:reference[starts-with(@value, 'https://') and contains(@value, $cur_valueSetID)] ) or
        not( v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/@id = $cur_valueSetID )">   
          <xsl:if test="not($cur_valueSetID = '')">                                                    
            <li>
            <xsl:text>Not Specified</xsl:text>                                     
              <ul>
                <li>                       
                <xsl:text>ValueSet: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$cur_valueSetID"></xsl:value-of> 
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>                 
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="v3:id/@root = $cur_valueSetID"> 
          <xsl:if test="v3:text/v3:reference[starts-with(@value, 'https://') and contains(@value, $cur_valueSetID)]">
            <xsl:if test="v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/@id = $cur_valueSetID">                 
              <li>       
                <xsl:text>Id: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="v3:id/@root"/>                               
                <xsl:for-each select="v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/rvs:ConceptList/rvs:Concept">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <xsl:if test="not(@code = '')">
                        <xsl:if test="@code">
                          <xsl:text>code = </xsl:text>
                          <xsl:value-of select="@code"></xsl:value-of>
                          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </li>
                  </ul>        
                </xsl:for-each>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>    
      </xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>                      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML input file 'I' xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QualityMeasureDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <component>
    <dataCriteriaSection>
      <definition>
        <valueSet>
          <!-- Value Set for Race -->
          <id root='1.1.1.1.1.1.1' />
          <text>
            <reference
              value='https://localhost/RetrieveValueSet?id=1.1.1.1.1.1.1' />
            <RetrieveValueSetResponse xmlns="urn:ihe:iti:svs:2008">
              <ValueSet id="1.1.1.1.1.1.1">
                <ConceptList>
                  <Concept code="4" />
                  <Concept code="5" />
                  <Concept code="6" />
                </ConceptList>
              </ValueSet>
            </RetrieveValueSetResponse>
          </text>
        </valueSet>
      </definition>
      <definition>
        <valueSet>
          <id root='1.1.1.1.1.1.2' />
          <text>
            <reference
              value='https://localhost/RetrieveValueSet?id=1.1.1.1.1.1.2' />
            <RetrieveValueSetResponse xmlns="urn:ihe:iti:svs:2008">
              <ValueSet id="1.1.1.1.1.1.2">
                <ConceptList>
                  <Concept code="007.2" />
                  <Concept code="007.3" />
                </ConceptList>
              </ValueSet>
            </RetrieveValueSetResponse>
          </text>
        </valueSet>
      </definition>
      <entry>
        <observationCriteria>
          <code code="424144002" codeSystem="123123213"
            displayName="FEWFW" />
          <value>
            <low />
            <high />
          </value>
        </observationCriteria>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <observationCriteria>
          <code code="DFHKJ" codeSystem="ASKJDHK" displayName="ASDNJK" />
          <value>
            <width />
          </value>
        </observationCriteria>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <observationCriteria>
          <code code="FDSFD" codeSystem="JHBHJB" displayName="HJGJH" />
          <value valueSet="1.1.1.1.1.1.1" />
        </observationCriteria>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <encounterCriteria>
          <code valueSet="1.1.1.1.1.1.2" />
        </encounterCriteria>
      </entry>
    </dataCriteriaSection>
  </component>
</QualityMeasureDocument>
```

**Expected Output Code 'I' HTML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<html xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:rvs="urn:ihe:iti:svs:2008" xmlns:v3="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <head>
    <title>Test 'I'</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Id: 1.1.1.1.1.1.1
        <ul>
          <li>code = 4 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>code = 5 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>code = 6 </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Id: 1.1.1.1.1.1.2
        <ul>
          <li>code = 007.2 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>code = 007.3 </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would be simple to create the correct output through a hack, or just erasing code, but this needs to work in all situations.  Such as, having no matches at all and displaying only the 'Not Specified' header and its string each time it occurs, or a mixture of both situations.  The code currently works in a situation where there are no matches, and displays the 'Not Specified' header and its string each time it occurs.

It seems like if this could be done, "if it's not a match AND hasn't already been listed" it would solve the problem.

Hope that helps.  If you would like more information or more files let me know.  Any tips at all would be great!  Thanks.

Comment: This is a *huge* amount of info - can you strip this apart and give the bare minimum?

Comment: Hi ABach, np - thanks for stopping by!  I spent hours stripping down my massive project into one little 3 template XSL file (and stripping code within those).  Then I guess I cluttered it back up with text and excess files.  Anyway, all gone - hope that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: An obvious problem with this code is that in many places *absolute* expressions of the type `//expr` are used and it is likely that what really is intended is a *relative* expression of the type `.//expr`. Also, there is some code duplication, which may be result of incorrect copy/paste. Finally, the monstrous expression in the `xsl:when` is most probably incorrect -- it would be a miracle if such complicated expression would be correct. I recommend to simplify this expression so that is more understandable. Also, run the transformation with a debugeer and see exactly where there is a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the info that is great to know for when I want to search for all instances within the same node set.  However, putting a . in front of the // for //v3:valueSet causes the code to output nothing.  I think this is because the matches are located in two different node sets, and definitionValueSet is being called from within a for-each (the previous location).  It needs to be // in order to compare the match to a new location.  At least one other instance in my code could be changed to what you suggested though so - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem you are having is within your named template "definitionValueSet", where you loop over **valueSet** elements with an **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet">
```

Within this you test whether the relevant attributes match your current parameter, and if you find a match, you output your list. But all **valueSet** elements will be searched, so even if one matches, you are still going to be processing the ones that don't and so your **xsl:if** for a non-match is called too. This results in the "Not Specified" being output.

What you really need to be doing is matching only the **valueSet** element if it exists, and if none exist that match, output your "Not Specified".

One way to do this is to first create a variable that holds the unique id of the **valueSet** element that matches

```
<xsl:variable name="valueSet">
   <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(//v3:valueSet[v3:id/@root = $cur_valueSetID and v3:text/v3:reference[starts-with(@value, 'https://') and contains(@value, $cur_valueSetID)] and v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/@id = $cur_valueSetID])"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, you can test whether this has been set, and if so, apply the template for that element. If not set, you can have your not-specified code

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$valueSet">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//v3:valueSet[generate-id() = $valueSet]"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- Not Specified -->
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Here is the full XSLT, which should hopefully give the output you require

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:v3="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:rvs="urn:ihe:iti:svs:2008">
   <xsl:output method="html" standalone="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>
   <xsl:template match="/v3:QualityMeasureDocument">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Test 'I'</title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <ul>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="//v3:dataCriteriaSection"/>
            </ul>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="v3:dataCriteriaSection">
      <xsl:for-each select=".//v3:entry">
         <xsl:if test="*/v3:value/@valueSet">
            <xsl:call-template name="definitionValueSet">
               <xsl:with-param name="cur_valueSetID" select="*/v3:value/@valueSet"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="*/v3:code/@valueSet">
            <xsl:call-template name="definitionValueSet">
               <xsl:with-param name="cur_valueSetID" select="*/v3:code/@valueSet"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="*/v3:participant/v3:roleParticipant/v3:code/@valueSet">
            <xsl:call-template name="definitionValueSet">
               <xsl:with-param name="cur_valueSetID" select="*/v3:participant/v3:roleParticipant/v3:code/@valueSet"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="definitionValueSet">
      <xsl:param name="cur_valueSetID"/>
      <xsl:variable name="valueSet">
         <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(//v3:valueSet[v3:id/@root = $cur_valueSetID and v3:text/v3:reference[starts-with(@value, 'https://') and contains(@value, $cur_valueSetID)] and v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/@id = $cur_valueSetID])"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$valueSet != ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//v3:valueSet[generate-id() = $valueSet]"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <li>
               <xsl:text>Not Specified</xsl:text>
               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <xsl:text>ValueSet: </xsl:text>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$cur_valueSetID"/>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="v3:valueSet">
      <li>
         <xsl:text>Id: </xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="v3:id/@root"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/rvs:ConceptList/rvs:Concept">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <xsl:if test="not(@code = '')">
                     <xsl:if test="@code">
                        <xsl:text>code = </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
                        <xsl:text/>
                     </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:if>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note, as mentioned in a comment, be careful with the use of expression `//v3:entry`. This is an absolute expression, and will match any element at all in the document (i.e it searches from the root element downwards). If you wanted only to look under the current element, use the relative expression `.//v3:entry`

EDIT: For a slight variant on this, as a potentially more efficient way to look up the **valueSet** elements you could define a key at the top of the XSLT document

```
<xsl:key name="valueSet" match="v3:valueSet" use="generate-id()" />
```

Then, instead of doing this to look up the correct **valueSet** element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//v3:valueSet[generate-id() = $valueSet]"/>
```

You could use the key instead

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('valueSet', $valueSet)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Tim!!!  I agree with your description of the problem and had thought of the storing it in a variable idea, but hadn't thought of a working implementation.  I think you are on the right track, but currently, I can't get your code (exactly as written), to display any 'Not Specified' when there is not match.  Whether it is just one unmatched id, or all of them.  If you can view my first draft of this question it includes an input file 'N' with no matches, or 'I' could just be edited to not match.  I will look into a solution using your ideas and study generate-id().

Comment: My apologies! There was mistake in my code that checked whether **valueSet** was set or not. I have corrected this now!

Comment: I'm glad that part pre-change was confusing me that's a good sign.  No need to apologize - thanks for returning so quick!  This solution is brilliant and your description in getting there is very helpful.  Thanks so much for taking the time to really dig into this problem.  Now it's my turn to dig into the solution for full understanding.  This will surely help me with similar situations in the future.  I am going to apply it to my full project now and hopefully everything goes smoothly w/o too many required changes.   Thanks again!

Comment: I found that <xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet[generate-id() = $valueSet]"> could also be used as opposed to having a separate template match applied.  I know that it is considered more correct to have a separate template, but, is there any functional difference?  Is one process more efficient than the other?  Thank you.  Would love to up-vote you (Tim) btw but I can't yet as per my current reputation.

Comment: Functionally they should be the same, but with the template you it could be used to match elements in a different parts of the code, much like a function can be called from multiple places. I am not sure about efficiency though, to be honest. I still have much to learn too!

Comment: Hi again.  I understand that the valueSet variable generates an id for a match, and the match is made when the conditions inside the generate id function are met.  I understand "$valueSetMatch != ''" checks if an id has been generated (it's not empty) so a match was found (correct?).  But, if you get a chance, could you explain the apply templates predicate [generate-id() = $valueSet]"/> ?  Is that a new id being generated and compared to the variable?  I see that the predicate limits matched duplicates, just not fully how.  Either way, you have been a great help, Thanks!

Comment: $valueSet will indeed contain the 'unique' id to identify the element. The point of the apply templates is that you then want to position yourself on the correct valueSet element, so that you can output the values of various child elements. This means searching through the XML until you find the element with the matching ID. I've added an edit to my answer to show how this could also be done with the use of an **xsl:key** which may make things clearer!

Comment: Hey Tim.  Thanks for expanding on your explanation, appreciate it.  I have come up with a new solution thanks to your help that I will add as well since it may be easier for new XSLT coders to understand.  However, I believe your solutions (specifically the key method) are far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple-ish alternate solution (does not use generate-id() or key() ) provided for comprehension.  It is likely less efficient than and should not replace Tim C's excellent answer.  I am simply providing this so people can learn, and to show that I put full effort into solving this issue, instead of just getting what I needed and moving on.

The solution is a fix to the original 'Problem Translator'.  The only section that needs to be edited (although heavily) from that XSL file is the "definitionValueSet" named template.

First we need to create a variable **$valueSetData** which stores all of the values of **v3:id/@root** in a one time pass, with a ',' in between them, in order to be individually referenced later.  It's like a new temporary database.
The for-each contains a predicate which limits the matches as per requirements.  These are included within the declaration because they are local nodes there.  Also, this keeps from processing extra conditional checks later.

```
<xsl:variable name="valueSetData">
   <xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet[
                           v3:text/v3:reference[starts-with(@value, 'https://') and contains(@value, $cur_valueSetID)] and 
                           v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/@id = $cur_valueSetID]">       
     <xsl:value-of select="v3:id/@root"/>
     <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Next we have the choose statement, edited for specifics.  The statement determines if there is a match to the **$cur_valueSetID** within the **$valueSetData** 'database'.
The for-each predicate limits duplicate matches (with the wrong values in addition due to context).

```
    <xsl:choose>    
      <xsl:when test="contains($valueSetData, $cur_valueSetID)"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet[$cur_valueSetID = v3:id/@root]">
          <!-- Display found matches which meet all requirements -->
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Display Not Specified -->
      </xsl:otherwise>                                                                            
    </xsl:choose>
```

The full "definitionValueSet" template:

```
  <xsl:template
    name="definitionValueSet">  
    <xsl:param name="cur_valueSetID"/>  
    <xsl:variable name="valueSetData">
       <xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet[
                               v3:text/v3:reference[starts-with(@value, 'https://') and contains(@value, $cur_valueSetID)] and 
                               v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/@id = $cur_valueSetID]">       
         <xsl:value-of select="v3:id/@root"/>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>                                     
    <xsl:choose>    
      <xsl:when test="contains($valueSetData, $cur_valueSetID)"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="//v3:valueSet[$cur_valueSetID = v3:id/@root]">
          <li>       
            <xsl:text>Id: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="v3:id/@root"/>                               
            <xsl:for-each select="v3:text/rvs:RetrieveValueSetResponse/rvs:ValueSet/rvs:ConceptList/rvs:Concept">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <xsl:if test="not(@code = '')">
                    <xsl:if test="@code">
                      <xsl:text>code = </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="@code"></xsl:value-of>
                      <xsl:text/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:if>
                </li>
              </ul>        
            </xsl:for-each>
          </li>            
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li>
          <xsl:text>Not Specified</xsl:text>                                     
          <ul>
            <li>                       
              <xsl:text>ValueSet: </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="$cur_valueSetID"></xsl:value-of> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li> 
      </xsl:otherwise>                                                                            
    </xsl:choose>   
  </xsl:template>
```